# JGIT: First iteration on an Iterable<RevCommit> result of log() empties it

Tags: git, logging, iterable, jgit

I just had a very confusing issue:
I'm using JGit and after retrieving a git log the returned result, an Iterable, will get emptied automatically if it is iterated.

Code:

```
Iterable<RevCommit> gitLog = git.log()
                              .addRange(refFromID, refToID)
                              .setRevFilter(RevFilter.NO_MERGES)        
                              .call();
System.out.println("Size of Iterable:  " + Iterables.size(gitLog)); //triggers first iteration. Size is >0
System.out.println("Size of Iterable:  " + Iterables.size(gitLog)); //second iteration triggered. Size is now = 0
```

Google didn't help in this case - I didn't find anything or anyone having this issue so far.

Even [resetting the RevWalk](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.1.3.201810200350-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevWalk.html) does not change anything:

"A RevWalk instance can only be used once to generate results. Running a second time requires creating a new RevWalk instance, or invoking reset() before starting again."
[...]

"reset(): Resets internal state and allows this instance to be used again." [...]

"The offered iterator is over the list of RevCommits described by the configuration of this instance. Applications should restrict themselves to using either the provided Iterator or next(), but never use both on the same RevWalk at the same time. The Iterator may buffer RevCommits, while next() does not."

Answer (score 0):

All the examples I can see only loop over that list *once*, as in [`jgit/api/CommitAndLogCommandTest.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/f40b39345cd9b54473ee871bff401fe3d394ffe3/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CommitAndLogCommandTest.java#L303-L321).

But any walker can be [reset in its walk order](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/2c8b366bdc5f40bcf3b100cc31de8430571e4149/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/WalkRev.java#L38-L44) to a certain commit [`eclipse/jgit/revwalk/ObjectWalk.java#markStart"`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/f40b39345cd9b54473ee871bff401fe3d394ffe3/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/ObjectWalk.java#L143-L193)

So try and reset your list to its first element *before* calling the second  `Iterables.size(gitLog)`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, the output of the second size() is still zero.

Comment: I edited my post. I found another hint of resetting the RevWalk with .reset(). But that also does not work.